# Code to analyze relationships between responses to different ranking questions on a survey

Tags: r, correlation, ranking, survey

My goal is to find much simpler code, which can generalize, that shows the relationships between responses to two survey questions.  In the MWE, one question asked respondents to rank eight marketing selections from 1 to 8 and the other asked them to rank nine attribute selections from 1 to 9.  Higher rankings indicate the respondent favored the selection more.  Here is the data frame.

```
structure(list(Email = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
"i"), Ads = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1), Alumni = c(3, 2, 2, 
3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2), Articles = c(6, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3), Referrals = c(4, 
3, 4, 8, 7, 8, 8, 6, 4), Speeches = c(7, 7, 6, 7, 4, 7, 4, 5, 
5), Updates = c(8, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 6), Visits = c(5, 8, 
7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 8), `Business Savvy` = c(10, 6, 10, 10, 4, 
4, 6, 8, 9), Communication = c(4, 3, 8, 3, 3, 9, 7, 6, 7), Experience = c(7, 
7, 7, 9, 2, 8, 5, 9, 5), Innovation = c(2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
1, 1), Nearby = c(3, 2, 2, 1, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2), Personal = c(8, 
10, 6, 8, 6, 10, 4, 3, 3), Rates = c(9, 5, 9, 6, 9, 7, 10, 5, 
4), `Staffing Model` = c(6, 8, 5, 5, 7, 5, 8, 7, 8), `Total Cost` = c(5, 
4, 3, 7, 8, 6, 9, 4, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

If numeric rankings cannot be used for my solution to calculating relationships (correlations), please correct me.

Hoping they can be used, I arrived at the following plodding code, which I hope calculates the correlation matrix of each method selection against each attribute selection.

```
library(psych)

dataframe2 <- psych::corr.test(dataframe[  , c(2, 9:17)])[[1]][1:10]  # the first method vs all attributes
dataframe3 <- psych::corr.test(dataframe[  , c(3, 9:17)])[[1]][1:10]  # the 2nd method vs all attributes and so on
dataframe4 <- psych::corr.test(dataframe[  , c(4, 9:17)])[[1]][1:10]  
dataframe5 <- psych::corr.test(dataframe[  , c(5, 9:17)])[[1]][1:10]
dataframe6 <- psych::corr.test(dataframe[  , c(6, 9:17)])[[1]][1:10]  
dataframe7 <- psych::corr.test(dataframe[  , c(7, 9:17)])[[1]][1:10]
dataframe8 <- psych::corr.test(dataframe[  , c(8, 9:17)])[[1]][1:10]

# create a dataframe from the rbinded rows
bind <- data.frame(rbind(dataframe2, dataframe3, dataframe4, dataframe5, dataframe6, dataframe7, dataframe8))
```

Rename rows and columns:

```
colnames(bind) <- c("Sel", colnames(dataframe[9:17]))
rownames(bind) <- colnames(dataframe[2:8])
```

How can I accomplish the above more efficiently?

By the way, the bind data frame also allows one to produce a heat map with the `DataExplorer` package.

```
library(DataExplorer)

DataExplorer::plot_correlation(bind)
```

[image: heat map of ranking correlations]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Summary]**

In the scope of our discussion, there are two ways to get the correlation data.

1. Use `stats::cor`, i.e., `cor(subset(dataframe, select = -Email))`
2. Use `psych::corr.test`, i.e., `corr.test(subset(dataframe, select = -Email))[[1]]`

Then you may subset the correlation matrix with the desired rows and columns.

In order to use `DataExplorer::plot_correlation`, you can simply do `plot_correlation(dataframe, type = "c")`. Note: the output heatmap will include correlations for all columns, so you can just ignore columns that are not of interests.

---

**[Original Answer]**

```
## Create data
dataframe <- structure(
  list(
    Email = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h",  "i"),
    Ads = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1),
    Alumni = c(3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2),
    Articles = c(6, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3),
    Referrals = c(4, 3, 4, 8, 7, 8, 8, 6, 4),
    Speeches = c(7, 7, 6, 7, 4, 7, 4, 5, 5),
    Updates = c(8, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 6),
    Visits = c(5, 8, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 8),
    `Business Savvy` = c(10, 6, 10, 10, 4, 4, 6, 8, 9),
    Communication = c(4, 3, 8, 3, 3, 9, 7, 6, 7),
    Experience = c(7, 7, 7, 9, 2, 8, 5, 9, 5),
    Innovation = c(2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1),
    Nearby = c(3, 2, 2, 1, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2),
    Personal = c(8, 10, 6, 8, 6, 10, 4, 3, 3),
    Rates = c(9, 5, 9, 6, 9, 7, 10, 5, 4),
    `Staffing Model` = c(6, 8, 5, 5, 7, 5, 8, 7, 8),
    `Total Cost` = c(5, 4, 3, 7, 8, 6, 9, 4, 6)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -9L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

Following your example strictly, we can do the following:

```
## Calculate correlation
df2 <- subset(dataframe, select = -Email)
marketing_selections <- names(df2)[1:7]
attribute_selections <- names(df2)[8:16]
corr_matrix <- psych::corr.test(df2)[[1]]
bind <- subset(corr_matrix,
               subset = rownames(corr_matrix) %in% marketing_selections,
               select = attribute_selections)
DataExplorer::plot_correlation(bind)
```

[image: Correlation Heatmap]

**WARNING**

However, is this what you really want? `psych::corr.test` generates the correlation matrix, and `DataExplorer::plot_correlation` calculates the correlation again. It is like the correlation of the correlation.

Comment: Excellent!   And you are correct, I do not want the correlation of the correlation.  Can you revise your answer so that I can use DataExplorer plot_correlation without that duplication?

Comment: @lawyeR If that is the case, couldn't you just do `DataExplorer::plot_correlation(dataframe, type = "c")`? It will include the other marketing selections columns as well, but you can simply ignore if you don't need them.

Comment: yes except that I want the data also, to be used in other ways, not just the heatmap.

Comment: @lawyeR To get the data, you can always do `cor(subset(dataframe, select = -Email))`, since that's exactly what `plot_correlation` does in the backend. If you want to use `psych::corr.test`, just use my 2nd code block, and `bind` is what you want. To plot, simply do `DataExplorer::plot_correlation(dataframe, type = "c")`.